# Gradients causing display error in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I've been having some trouble properly displaying a couple of inline-block div's in Microsoft Edge. The second div loses the border or is just shown as a big black box. I'm using Windows 10 on an HTML5 page. Internet Explorer and other browsers seem to work fine. After some fiddling around I narrowed the problem down to the following lines:

```css
div {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

div button {
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  background: #428a00;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #428a00 0%, #4fa600 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #428a00 0%, #4fa600 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #428a00 0%, #4fa600 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#428a00', endColorstr='#4fa600', GradientType=0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
<div>Conditions</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy4htbpt/5/)

I can remove either of the border properties, the display: inline-block property, or the gradient properties and everything shows just fine. Now I'm wondering, is this an error in Edge? I've checked and re-checked the css gradients and everything seems to be in order. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have Windows 10 and Microsoft Edge 38.14393.1066.0. No problems. https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/ytbcfq2n/

Comment: Your JSFiddle renders the same in Edge as it does in Chrome for me. Try it on another device. This might be an issue with your video driver (I know crazy, but that has been the issue for me in the past with these sort of things).

I am on a Surface Pro 3 with the latest insiders Windows 10 build

Comment: This is an absolute useless comment so, please, ignore it: ANY issues on ie... since forever, are not worth to spend a single 5 minutes trying to solve it. We have some, very big, web apps with many clients paying monthly and we decided like 2 years ago... before edge, to tell to our clientes "this is a chrome web, it works fine on safari and ios but you could find some issues, This web doesn't work well enough on explorer"

Comment: @Alvaro: Explorer is not the problem here

Comment: I had to convince my boss for years and.... once I did.  we didn't lose any client. IE sucks and will always sucks. VERy big example: Something as important and usefull as `object-fit: cover` (it is amazing) Are already valid in all browsers but ie. (on development.. they say).

Comment: Well, Gerad. The question is "display error on Edge". It is truth that I'm not in a very good mood and used the question to rant. If Im wrong I so apologise... should read before rant. Sorry

Comment: Use this at the end `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #428a00 0%, #4fa600 100%);`, maybe that helps.

Comment: I'm on Microsoft Edge 38.14393.1066.0 as well but it never occured to me that it could be a video driver issue. Thanks for the feedback. I realize spending time on Edge is pointless but it was just such an odd bug for something relatively simple.